# Enviar archivo pdf, reciencreado con jspdf

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, jspdf

mi problema es el siguiente, yo creo por javascript un pdf a partir de un formulario y me funciona, pero ahora ese archivo pdf lo tengo que mandar al mismo tiempo al correo que el usuario introdujo en el formulario, espero me pueden recomendar u orientar como hacerlo

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btn_pdf').click(function () {


        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.body, function () {
            pdf.save('RegistroHunucma.pdf');
        });



    });
});
```

Comment: Solo se pueden enviar correos por medio de un backend, tu solo estas usando frontend para crear el PDF, si deseas enviar ese PDF a algun correo deberas usar un backend si es que no dispones de uno aun, en caso de que ya tengas un backend te falto poner en las etiquetas que backend estas usando.

Comment: Para enviar un correo no lo hace el frontend, tienes que conectarte a un backend, haces una transferencia del archivo nuevo por `FormData()` y procesarlo del otro lado, o mejor aún, enviar los datos del formulario y que el backend se encargue se crear el PDF y enviarlo.

Comment: estoy usando c#, tenia pensado guardar el archivo en el proyecto de forma temporal, mandarlo y luego eliminarlo pero no se como

Comment: C# en conjunto con javascript?, te falto entonces tambien mencionar en las etiquetas que estas usando jsp, que creo que es el framework que permite la comunicacion entre ellos, aunque no se si me equivoco y estas usando en vez de jsp, .NET framework. de todas maneras como te decimos, el problema no es almacenar el archivo, el problema es que para enviar correos solo puedes hacerlo mediante un backend, que estas usando como backend?, de todas maneras creo que en jsp (si es que usas jsp) debe haber una forma de usar C# como backend.

Comment: Estoy haciendo una aplicacion web con asp.net framework, en c# con javascript, el pdf lo genero con jspdf, como puedo pasar ese archivo reciencreado al backend?

Comment: La mejor opción es que, Javascript no haga ese archivo. Envia tu formulario al backend por medio de `$.ajax()` y utiliza herramientas escritas en C# para crear PDF y ahí mismo configuras otra herramienta para el envío de emails. Antepongo que para esto, debes tener ya un servidor de correo electrónico.

Comment: Por motivos del proyecto lo tengo que generar con Javascript ya que es la manera mas viable, por eso quiero enviar el correo por ahi si es posible